# how to add order name in pos receipt?

Tags: odoo

I'm using openerp 6.1.1 and in the web client, the pos receipt doesn't have the pos order number. The receipt is defined in pos.xml in the module. How to call the same receipt in pos backend or how could i add the order no: in the web pos receipt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Openerp forum i've found an answer. just add the foll. code in pos.xml.

```
<t t-esc="widget.currentOrder.getName()"/><br />
```

under

```
    <t t-name="pos-ticket">
    <div class="pos-sale-ticket">
    <div class="pos-right-align"><t t-esc="new Datee().toString(Date.CultureInfo.formatPatterns.shortDate + ' ' +
Date.CultureInfo.formatPatterns.longTime)"/></div>
    <br />
    <t t-esc="widget.company.name"/><br />
    Phone: <t t-esc="widget.company.phone || ''"/><br />
    User: <t t-esc="widget.user.name"/><br />
    Shop: <t t-esc="widget.shop_obj.name"/><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

In the pos-ticket object in the file, add:

```
Order:<t t-esc="widget.currentOrder.getName()"/><br />
```

Then restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

for odoo8 the correct line is: `<t t-esc="widget.pos.get_client().name" />`